# Azure Storage Queue and At Most Once Delivery

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I was under the impression that this was not available with storage queue but after investigating I can't find proof of this.

MSDN articles say At-Least-Once but the most information I can find is that the first consumer gets the message and sets the message to invisible.

Then when it becomes visible again it could be picked up again.

However I could set invisible to a large TimeSpan and I could check Dequeue count to limit it to At-Most-Once delivery.

This is using the assumption that competing consumers can't grab the same message at the same time which I can't verify.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether Storage Queues offer at most once delivery, the answer is no. If you need at most once, use Service Bus queues. See the Foundational Capabilities section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted