# Azure storage queue triggered function starts multiple times

Tags: azure, function

All,

I have storage queue triggered Azure Function. It loads various data into a database from files. I specify the input file in the message sent into the input queue.
However when I send a message into the queue my function starts in multiple instances and tries to insert the same file into the db. If I log msg.dequeue_count I see it rising.

What shall I do to start only one function for each message? Please note I'd like to keep the possibility to start multiple instance for multiple messages to load different files parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question was also asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272060/azure-storage-queue-and-at-most-once-delivery) and the answer was to check out the [chart comparing storage and service bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted).

Bottom line is that storage queues offer 'at least once' delivery. If you want 'at most once' you should use service bus and [PeekLock or ReceiveAndDelete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions#receive-modes).